# Troubles with simple pokemon battle in C#

Tags: c#, function

I'm making a very simple Pokemon battle game with C#. The main idea is that every 5 turns the first `Pokemon` (`Squirtle`) powers up his damage with a function.
But when I compile it, the damage of `Squirtle` is the same. Any of idea what's happening?

Here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace FirstProgram
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[]args)
        {
            int turn = 1;

            int potion1 = 0;

            //Creando y declarando Pikachu
            Pokemon Pikachu = new Pokemon();

            Pikachu.health = 190;

            Pikachu.damage = 40;
            //Creando y declarando Squirtle

            Pokemon Squirtle = new Pokemon();

            Squirtle.health = 190;

            Squirtle.damage = 40;

            while (Pikachu.health > 0 && Squirtle.health > 0)
            {
                if(turn == 1)
                {
                    Squirtle.health = Squirtle.health - Pikachu.damage;

                    turn = 0;

                    potion1++;

                    Console.WriteLine("Pikachu atacks!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Squirtle has only " + Squirtle.health + " PV!");

                    if(potion1 == 5)
                    {
                        potion1 = 0;
                        Squirtle.MoreDamage(Squirtle.damage);
                        Console.WriteLine("Squirtle damage now it's  " + Squirtle.damage);
                    }                 
                }
                else
                {
                    Pikachu.health = Pikachu.health - Squirtle.damage;
                    turn = 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Squirtle atacks!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Pikachu has only " + Pikachu.health + " PV!");
                }
            }

            if(Pikachu.health > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pikachu wins!");
            }
            else if(Squirtle.health > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Squirtle wins!");
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

### Pokemon.cs

```
class Pokemon
{
    //Declarando la vida y el ataque
    public int health;
    public int damage;

    //Creando metodo para aumentar el ataque
    public  void MoreDamage(powerup)
    {
        powerup= powerup+ 5;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:
[image: output]

I tried to do other things, like changing the code of the function, but all of the tries have the same result: the `damage` doesn't power up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MoreDamage()` method is only modifying the `powerup` parameter. You need to edit the `Pokemon`'s `damage` property instead.

Change this:

```
public  void MoreDamage(powerup)
{
    powerup= powerup+ 5;
}
```

to this:

```
public void MoreDamage(int powerup)
{
    damage += powerup;
}
```

Then, change your call to `MoreDamage()` to pass the value you want to increase the Pokemon's damage by:

```
Squirtle.MoreDamage(5);
```